# emacs find file at point double backslashes on windows

Tags: windows, emacs, escaping

My problem is that I want to be able to navigate to directories like:

```
"..\\A\\B\\a.blah"
```

Currently, when i use the ffap command, it works for:

```
"../A/B/a.blah"
"..//A//B//a.blah"
"..\A\B\a.blah"
```

but it doesn't work for

```
"..\\A\\B\\a.blah"
```

now I found a mailing list relating to this ([here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2008-01/msg00758.html)) but this I think solves it only for the backslash. Do I have to add something to my ffap-string-at-point variable?

Here's the value of it currently:

```
ffap-string-at-point-mode-alist is a variable defined in ‘ffap.el’.
Its value is ((file "--:\\\\${}+<>@-Z_[:alpha:]~*?" "<@" "@>;.,!:")
 (url "--:=&?$+@-Z_[:alpha:]~#,%;*()!'" "^[0-9a-zA-Z]" ":;.,!?")
 (nocolon "--9$+<>@-Z_[:alpha:]~" "<@" "@>;.,!?")
 (machine "-[:alnum:]." "" ".")
 (math-mode ",-:$+<>@-Z_[:lower:]~`" "<" "@>;.,!?`:")
 (latex-mode "--:\\\\$+<>@-Z_[:alpha:]~*?" "<@" "@>;.,!:")
 (tex-mode "--:\\\\$+<>@-Z_[:alpha:]~*?" "<@" "@>;.,!:"))


  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.

Documentation:
Alist of (MODE CHARS BEG END), where MODE is a symbol,
possibly a major-mode name, or one of the symbols
‘file’, ‘url’, ‘machine’, and ‘nocolon’.
Function ‘ffap-string-at-point’ uses the data fields as follows:
1. find a maximal string of CHARS around point,
2. strip BEG chars before point from the beginning,
3. strip END chars after point from the end.
The arguments CHARS, BEG and END are handled as described in
‘skip-chars-forward’.
```

Comment: Have you tried using exactly the same `file` element as is proposed in the [link](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2008-01/msg00758.html), which is said to work?

Comment: Have you abandoned your post?

Comment: not yet! Just been busy the last few days

Comment: im not sure how to find the ffap-string-at-point variable, i've tried using describe-variable, but it's not in scope, not can I find the ffap.el file in my .emacs.d

Comment: You could search for `ffap.el` over the whole disk.

Comment: i tried this: sudo find / -name *ffap*
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/types/offapi.rdb
/usr/share/emacs/25.1/lisp/ffap.elc
/usr/share/emacs/25.1/lisp/ffap.el.gz

Comment: however, it looks like ffap.elc is compiled in some form

Comment: ah looks like it's in the ffap.el.gz file

Comment: so i changed the ffap.el.gz file to the one in the link, which has the problem worse. Now all backslashes don't work in ffap :(